# Highlighting cells in row 3,6,9,12 that are less than 0.05 in yellow

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to highlight in yellow cells that are less than 0.05 in row 3, 9, 12 and also the cell above and below the selected ones. anyone has any idea? really appreciated!

I tried this code and it works but is there's a more efficient way to do this? i.e. looping the column instead of typing in the B, C, D... etc

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long

For i = 3 To 16 Step 3

```
  If Range("B" & i).Value < 0.5 Then Range("B" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
  If Range("B" & i).Value < 0.5 Then Range("B" & i).Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
  If Range("B" & i).Value < 0.5 Then Range("B" & i).Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

  If Range("C" & i).Value < 0.5 Then Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
  If Range("C" & i).Value < 0.5 Then Range("C" & i).Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
  If Range("C" & i).Value < 0.5 Then Range("C" & i).Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Please give a look on the [Conditional Formatting in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx), that can basically help you to color the cells you need providing some sort of customized condition (in your case select rows 3,9 and 12 and apply the condition).
To color the cell above (for example) check if the cell "below the above" (your current cell) is less than 0.05

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I am actually thinking of doing it through a vba code. Would be great to know more!

Comment: Well in that case you can use a loop to scan all your populated cells and check if they met your requirements (their value is <0.05). In that case select those and those below and above (hint: you can use `.Offset(-1,0)` and `.Offset(1,0)` to address them) and color them (for example `.interior.colorindex = 6` which is yellow).
;) I gave you the idea, but please show the community your effort :)

Comment: I tried this code and it works but I'm just wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this? i.e. looping the column instead of typing in the B, C, D... etc

Comment: Well as I suggested "in that case you can use a loop to scan all your populated cells". That would mean that you can use an `Do Until IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i,4))` for example, where i is the row-counter that increases each time, 4 is the 4th column. This command will loop through every single cell in the 4th row until it finds an empty one.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with your outer loop and can add a loop through the columns like you asked and I demonstrated below. I compressed your three if statements per loop iteration into one and added an else condition to clear old colors if the criteria is not met. Obviously change the worksheet name to whatever you need it to be. It is a good practice to create a worksheet reference and thereby use ws.Range instead of just Range. It helps make sure Excel is working on the sheet you think it's working on. This should at least get you close.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    For row = 3 To 15 Step 3
        For col = 2 To ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If ws.Cells(row, col).Value < 0.5 And ws.Cells(row, col).Value <> "" Then
                ws.Range(Cells(row - 1, col), Cells(row + 1, col)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Else
                ws.Range(Cells(row - 1, col), Cells(row + 1, col)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNoFill
            End If
        Next col
    Next row
End Sub
```